# Split in different scenario

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My NewsTypeName come like this,
**Scenario 1**,
GLOBAL NEWS (20)
**Scenario 2**,
GLOBAL NEWS (2)

In here i want to get the number( 20 and 2 ).

> > I want to filter the number.
> >     My Code

```
NewsTypeName.Split('(')[1].Remove(2); // thisone correctfor Scenario 1.In here i get 20,when i use it for scenario 2 it getting error..
```

Comment: You would be better off using regex for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove last character from string and then split as shown :-

```
NewsTypeName.Remove(NewsTypeName.Length - 1).Split('(')[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) and do this.

```
string NewsTypeName = "GLOBAL NEWS (20)";
var number =  NewsTypeName.Split('(', ')')[1];

// output - 20
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript

```
var str ="GLOBAL NEWS (20)";
var arr =str.split(" ");
alert(arr[arr.length-1].replace("(","").replace(")",""));
```